# Wildcard query doesn't return results although query_string with wildcard works

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

Given this mapping

```
"mappings": {
    "schools": { 
        "properties": {
            "autocomplete": {
                "type": "string"
            } 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This query is working:

```
GET records-schools/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "my_*al",
            "default_field": "autocomplete",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10
}
```

But this one, doesn't:

```
GET records-schools/_search
{
   "query": {
       "wildcard": {
           "autocomplete": "my_*al"
       }
   },
   "from": 0,
   "size": 10
}
```

Although, if I change the value of the last query to a simple asterisk `*`, *it works*.

Why isn't the wildcard query working?

*Notes:*
ElasticSearch version: 2.4

Comment: You should try the `prefix` query instead of `wildcard`

Comment: @Val What if the wildcard is at the second character? e.g. `m*_val`

Comment: Maybe the reason is the fact that wildcard does not analyze the query. I think the "my_val" is split into "my" and "val" by default tokenizer. Because the default operator in `query_string` is `OR` what you really get is probably "my OR *al" and that's why you get a match. But that's just a guess I didn't check it.